# When was gcc last updated in my system?

Tags: centos, gcc

Is it possible to know the last update date of gcc in Centos? If yes, how can it be checked? The problem is that one my applications, which used to run before in gcc, is not running in gcc.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more useful to look at the version number (`gcc -v`) than the date?

Answer (score 0):

`rpm -qi gcc` should give you the build date and install date of the package, among other information. (However, I don't have access to a CentOS system to test it right now.)